# Load more than 100 URLs in more than 100 UIWebview without the load error

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

So I have more than 100 `UIWebViews` that loads different URLs and it just load few URLs and the other it shows me this in the console `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810)` is there's any way to load them without any error or this is based on my internet connection?

Comment: You probably need to take a look at your application design. How can you display 100 web views on screen at the same time?  If they aren't all displayed, don't load them all at once.

Comment: If it complains about SSLHandshake, then there must be something wrong with your SSL certificate on the server.

Comment: You are opening 100 safari in you application, think about it.